# React Native Android Hardware Back button not working properly

Tags: android, react-native, wix-react-native-navigation

> LoginScreen.js

```
this.props.navigator.push({
      screen: "auxxa.LandingScreen",
      passProps: { login: true },
      overrideBackPress: true,
      navigatorStyle: {
        navBarHidden: true
      }
    });
```

> LandingScreen.js

```
 constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.handleBackButtonClick = this.handleBackButtonClick.bind(this);
    //  this.props.navigator.setOnNavigatorEvent(this.onNavigatorEvent.bind(this));
    this.state = {
      size: { width, height },
      tileData: null,
      isLoading: true,
      user_id: null,
      refetching: false,
      access_token: null
    };
  }
  componentWillMount() {
    BackHandler.addEventListener(
      "hardwareBackPress",
      this.handleBackButtonClick
    );
  }
  handleBackButtonClick() {
    console.log("check login " + this.props.login);
    if (this.backPressed && this.backPressed > 0) {
      if (this.props.login) {
        console.log("login");
        RNExitApp.exitApp();
      } else {
        console.log("root");
        this.props.navigator.popToRoot({ animated: false });
        return false;
      }
    }

    this.backPressed = 1;
    this.props.navigator.showSnackbar({
      text: "Press one more time to exit",
      duration: "long"
    });
    return true;
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    BackHandler.removeEventListener(
      "hardwareBackPress",
      this.handleBackButtonClick
    );
}
```

> I used **react-native-navigation from Wix** for my app nevigation purpose.Here I have attached login screen and landing screen.after successful login app navigate to landing screen.after that I click back button It will return to login screen.I need to avoid that.How can I do that thing? I tried to exit from the app.But it also not working properly.
>   Please help me if some one know this.Thanks in advanced.

Answer (score 1):

Use this call in handleBackButtonClick function and why are you removing the listener in componentDidMount ?

```
this.props.navigator.resetTo({  screen: 'example.ScreenThree'})
```

.

Comment: Hi I need to exit from the app.How can I change this according to that?

Comment: BackAndroid.exitApp() try this.

Comment: Anyway, exit the app is not a nice practice. The way an app should be closed is by closing from app open view.

Answer (score 0):

Uncomment `this.props.navigator.setOnNavigatorEvent(this.onNavigatorEvent.bind(this));` on your constructor to listen to navigation events
and add the navigationEvent listener method

```
onNavigatorEvent(event: NavigatorEvent) {
  if (event.type === 'NavBarButtonPress') {
    if (event.id === 'skill_information') {
      // Add here whatever you would like to do (this.handleBackButtonClick() for example)
    }
  }
```